# telethon bot sending too many photos, and not looping properly

Tags: telegram, telethon

with this bot i want to send x photos after i click a button and input a number in the console.
1 problem - it won't loop properly, after i click the button on the bot it sends the foto ecc and it's ok. if i try again it won't work.

2 problem - if i input 3 the bot sends 4 photos

this is the code:

```
bottoni = [
    [  
        Button.inline("invia foto", b"1"), 
        Button.inline("seconda opzione", b"2")
    ],
    [
        Button.inline("terza opzione", b"3"), 
        Button.inline("quarta opzione", b"4")
    ],
      ]
i = 0
bot = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
print ("bot e userbot startati!")
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="/start"))
async def start(event):
    await event.respond(".       --benvenuto nel bot--       .")

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="opzioni"))
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="Opzioni"))
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="/opzioni"))
async def handler(event):
    await bot.send_message("myuser",".       --queste sono le opzioni--       .",buttons= bottoni)

@bot.on(events.CallbackQuery)
async def handler(event):
    global i
    global path
    if event.data == b"1":
        await event.respond("quante foto devo mandare? / guarda console") 
    numerofoto = int(input("quante foto devo mandare? ")) 
    while i <= numerofoto:
        path = (r"C:\path\to\folder\with\photos")
    fotorandom = random.choice([
        os.path.join(path, x)
        for x in os.listdir(path)  
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
])
    i += 1

    await event.reply(file=fotorandom)
```

Comment: this is clearly an issue not related to telethon, also stop using global variables.

Comment: bruh i fixed the +1 photos just by i = 1, and i was asking a way to fix the first problem:
it won't loop properly, after i click the button on the bot it sends the foto ecc and it's ok. if i try again it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

kk fixed tho.

i just added

```
    if i >= numerofoto:
    i = 0
    print("foto mandate: " + str(numerofoto))
```

after `await event.reply(file=fotorandom)`

this fixes both the problems.